# How do I get batch to recognise a folder with a . in as a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which needs to **rename** a folder from `Profile.Win7` to `Profile.Win7.%currentdate%`.

Right now I'm just using the command

```
move /y %userprofileaddress%\Profile.Win7 %userprofileaddress%\%backupfolder%
```

which doesn't throw an error (as far as I can see) but just doesn't do anything.

The folder isn't in use, so any ideas?

---

Edit: It works now... I wasn't running as admin. *facepalm*

Comment: Copy only copies files not folders. Folders can have as many dots in their name as they want. Windows don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easier to obtain answers if you directly describe the corresponding processing and results of the batch file in the question.

Both works well and not work examples. And if there are error messages etc.

According to the contents of the current question, it seems that it renames the folder itself rather than moving or copying the files in the folder.

In that case, if there is a program using the corresponding folder and files and folders in it, you should not be able to rename.

Please check whether such a situation has occurred.

Comment: Edited the original post.